# winsock2 P2P without port forwarding

Tags: c, p2p, winsock2

I am new to winsock2 and networking in general but I am not new to C.

My goal is to make a program that can send and receive data from one computer to another.

Basically I want to make something like this:
Computer one initializes a transfer with computer two. Computer one does know the IP address of computer two but computer two does not know the IP address of computer one. So in other words computer two can be though of as a server and computer one as a client.

I would like for this to work without either of the users need to mess with router settings such as forwarding ports. My idea was to make something like an HTTP server. The reason for this is because pretty much all routers can view webpages which regularly send and receive data which is my goal. And just like what I want to do, the server does not know the clients IP address until the client tries to request something from the server. So with that said I realize that I should model my program off of HTTP. I decided to first write a simple program testing the programs ability to send a webpage.

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static const char html[]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
"<html>\r\n"
"<head>\r\n"
"<title>Html Test</title>\r\n"
"</head>\r\n"
"<body>\r\n";
static const char htmlend[]="</body>\r\n"
"</html>\r\n\r\n";
static const char * defaultStr="Default";
int main(void){
    int exit=0;
    WSADATA wsa;
    char buffer[512];
    int bytes;
    SOCKET s,client;
    SOCKADDR_IN localAddress;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
    while(!exit){
        char * str;
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        localAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        localAddress.sin_port = htons(80);
        localAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        bind(s, (SOCKADDR*)&localAddress, sizeof(localAddress));
        listen(s, SOMAXCONN);
        client = accept(s,NULL,NULL);
        closesocket(s);
        bytes = recv(client,buffer,512,0);
        fputs(buffer,stdout);
        str=strstr(buffer,"GET /")+5;
        if(str){
            char *str3;
            if(*str==' '){
                str=(char*)defaultStr;
            }else{
                char *str2=strstr(str," ");
                *str2=0;
                if(!strcmp(str,"Exit"))
                    exit=1;
            }
            puts(str);
            str3=malloc(strlen(html)+strlen(htmlend)+strlen(str)+6);
            strcpy(str3,html);
            strcat(str3,str);
            strcat(str3,"\r\n");
            strcat(str3,htmlend);
            fputs(str3,stdout);
            send(client,str3,strlen(str3),0);
            free(str3);
        }
        shutdown(client,SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(client);
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue with the above program is that it works only on internal network. When I try to access it on the world wide web nothing happens. Am I even taking the right approach (simulating http for P2P?)? What is wrong with my program that it does not work on the world wide web? If anyone has an answer to either or both of these questions I thank you in advanced.